# PHP IF AND statement won't execute else section

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to use an IF AND statement in PHP to test for

1. The submit button being pressed and
2. That my `$testemail` varable is equal to one, ie valid email in a PHP script.

If the Email is good , I get:
Thank you, 1  //  ( this is correct) and email is sent

If the email is bad I get:
Thank you, 0.  //  ( this is not correct ) and email is still trying to be sent with bad email address.

Because the script is outputting the 0 or 1 properly, I am certain it has tested the email and correctly deciding if it is good or bad ( hence the `'0'` and the `'1'`) but the script never goes to the else statement. I can't seem to get the IF AND statement right. I have tried `"1"` and `'1'`.

Very confused. Thanks in advance.

```
if(!filter_var($emailtmp, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
  $testemail = "0";
}
else
{
  $testemail = "1";
}

global $testemail;
var_dump($testemail);

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && ($testemail = 1) )       
{       
    //Everything is good, proceed
    sendEmail(preg_replace(array('/<td>.*href="\?remove.*<\/td>/i', '/<th.*&nbsp;    
         <\/th>/i'), '', $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART_HTML']));
    $result_message = "Thank You.  $testemail ";
}
elseif (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //Missing Required Information
    $result_message = "You must use a Valid email addresse, $testemail  ";
}
```

Comment: Carl already pointed out the main problem, but why check `isset($_POST['submit'])` twice?

Comment: `($testemail = 1)` you're assigning instead of comparing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
($testemail = 1)
```

should be

```
($testemail === 1)
```

Having just `($testemail = 1)` simply sets the value of testemail to 1 (which for the purposes of the if, is true since its successful). `==` or better yet the more exact `===` is what you want for checking if the left & right values match.

Comment: With $testemail =1 you are setting $testemail to 1 (effectively overwriting it), which always works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are assigning the value 1 to `$testemail` instead of comparing it.